# Create JSON array from shell array with jq

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

We are trying to get `jq`v1.5 64bit to parse an array then echo out the result.

Do we have the correct `jq` syntax?

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a nameArr 
nameArr=("Leia" "Darth Vader" "Anakin" "Han Solo" "Yoda")
jq -c -n  "$nameArr"
```

gives error

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
Leia,    
jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: How should your output look like?

Comment: Note, btw, that `jq -c -n "$nameArr"` passes only the first element of the array, so it runs `jq -c -n "Leia,"` with your original input. There isn't a good way to pass a shell array (which can contain any list of valid C strings) *inside* a single C string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you are right with the comma. I did add that as a typo when creating the question. Thanks for the catch, I have updated to actual array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use a sigil that can't possibly exist as a value in a shell array, NUL is an appropriate choice.

```
nameArr=( "Leia" "Darth Vader" "Anakin" "Han Solo" "Yoda" )
printf '%s\0' "${nameArr[@]}" | jq -csR 'split("\u0000")'
```

...properly emits:

```
["Leia","Darth Vader","Anakin","Han Solo","Yoda"]
```